# Bootstrap Card with Navbar - How to Load New Content without Loading New Page?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working with Django to build a simple website, and in one of my my pages, `analysis.html`, I call the Twitter API to load some data.

In `analysis.html`, I have this card that I got from Bootstrap's components:

```
<div class="card text-center" style="width: 800px;">
  <div class="card-header">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills card-header-pills">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#buttona" style="color:#1DA1F2">Content A</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#buttonb" style="color:#1DA1F2">Content B</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Content A</h5>
    <p class="card-text">
    // Content A Stuff
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's 2 buttons, `Content A` and `Content B`, and upon clicking `Content A` I'd like the page to load content A stuff only inside the card, and similarly for `content B`.

I'm fairly new to HTML, so my first thought was to just load a new page, say `analysisA.html`, upon someone clicking button A, and `anaysisB.html` upon someone clicking button B, where everything on the HTML template is the same except for content A/B.

But this seems like bad coding, and it'd be calling the Twitter API unnecessarily, as all the necessary data is already called when `analysis.html` is opened.

So, how should I go about swapping the content back and forth in the card only, while keeping everything else in the page the same? Thank you.

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Comment: see this and set your template  using ajax call

Comment: "l the necessary data is already called when analysis.html is opened. " Both content A and B are in the page at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use a javascript framework like AngularJS to load your page content, but since bootstrap uses jQuery you could take advantage of the jQuery based load function. For instance:

```
$("#contentA").click(function() {
  //Load an entire external page in to contentA
  $( "#contentB" ).load( "analysisB.html div#content" );
  //Load just a piece of data from an external file in to contentA
  $( "#contentB" ).load( "analysisB.html" );
})
```

Comment: Where should I place this in the code? Right after ``<div class="card-body">``?

Comment: You can use the jquery preload functionality and place this in the head if you want "$(function() {
    //Code
});". Otherwise you need to put this at the end of your document.